# Tflearn on Windows10, anaconda

Tags: windows, anaconda, tflearn

I installed tflearn using pip install tflearn. It installs alright, no error message, but when I try to import it gives error (on Pycharm and Jupyter Notebook error reads: Import error: No module named Tflearn)

But on Powershell more details are available: [Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRV5c.png)

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling of the import in your code. You have to `import tflearn`, not Tflearn.

Comment: Kindly check the image, the spellings are correct, I have written import tflearn directly at the python interpreter on the console. And the corresponding error message.

Comment: My fault, sorry. There seems to be a problem with your numpy installation. What version of tensorflow and numpy do you use? `python -c "import numpy;print numpy.version;print numpy.file";`

Comment: I have tried it in 
1. Python 3.5, Tensorflow 1.1 and Numpy 1.12.1
2. Python 3.5 Tensorflow 1.3 and Numpy 1.13.1

Comment: Did you activate your environment before trying to run tensorflow? `source activate yourenvname`?

Comment: Yes, I did, it is Powershell, so not showing the change in command prompt after activate env.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks @Thomas for all your responses.
The problem solved after I performed:
 1. Uninstall tflearn.
 2. Update conda
 3. Install tflearn again